# How Secure is out of the box forms authentication in asp.net mvc 3?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, security

If I take the generic out of the box MVC3 skeleton site with a login and host it, how secure is the content behind the login?  Are there known exploits of Microsoft's forms authentication?  Can I trust that the authentication process, and the `[Authorize]` protection hold weight?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ASP.NET Forms authentication is a proven technology, so the Authorize attribute is OK. But since you asked about the skeleton ASP.NET MVC application that's generated for you, well, it has flaws. For example the LogOn method on the Account controller is not decorated with the `[RequireHttps]` attribute which means that you can access it over a non secure channel. There was another flaw in the authentication method that didn't verify that the ReturnUrl parameter was actually an url that belonged on the same domain. This was fixed in the ASP.NET MVC 3 Tools Update.

There are also other flaws in the authentication section in `web.config`:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
```

Here the `requireSSL` attribute is not set to `true` meaning that the authentication cookie could be transmitted over a non-secure channel. Also the `slidingExpiration` property is not set to false meaning that the cookie will be automatically renewed on each request. I would recommend you taking a look at the [following guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648341.aspx).

Comment: if the site is not run on https, will the requiressl attribute or requirehttps have any affect?  Is the site non secure if run on http?

Comment: @TravisJ, of course that it will have effect. If you run your site on HTTP, and you have set requireSSL property to true, you will never be able to authenticate as your browser will never send the authentication cookie to the server over a non-secure channel. Which is a good thing because that's how you strengthen up the security. By using the `[RequireHttps]` attribute on your Account controller you will force all HTTP requests to be redirected to HTTPS.